# AM335x watchdog does not work

Tags: embedded-linux, watchdog, cortex-a8, texas-instruments, omap

I am currently working on TI AM335x board (Starter Kit) and I would like to get the OMAP watchdog working...

As far as I know the platform automatically enables the watchdog during boot and I think it is confirmed by the following messages printed out at boot:

```
[    1.510192] OMAP Watchdog Timer Rev 0x01: initial timeout 60 sec
```

If I am not wrong at this point if I issue the following command:

```
echo 0 > /dev/watchdog
```

the board should reboot in 60 seconds, isn't it? Instead after 60 seconds nothing happens... why? Am I missing something relevant about that? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution on my own.

As clearly told [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_PSP_WDT_Driver_User_Guide), the file `/dev/watchdog` must be kept open for allowing the watchdog to fire... then the right command for causing the watchdog fire is:

```
cat > /dev/watchdog
```

and then type 0: after 60 seconds the board will reboot.

Comment: Had the exact same problem on my AM3352 system.

Comment: If the kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT=y`, the watchdog will not be disabled when you close `/dev/watchdog`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessarily to keep /dev/watchdog open, if you push-on "disable watchdog timer support" (avaliable in Device Drivers->Watchdog Timer Support->...) feature on kernel menuconfig.

Comment: Which defeat the purpose of the watchdog timer in the first place.

Comment: Start again when everything was frozen... Isn't pretty solution?